# Проблема с kartik export menu

Tags: ajax, yii2

Блок с таблицей генерируется с помощью ajax

```
$this->renderAjax('export-table');
```

после чего экспорт меню перестает работать, подскажите кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как можно ее победить ? видел всего несколько вопросов на эту тему в интернете но на них не кто так и не дал ответ